# Does shooting people make them dislike me?

Tags: stardew-valley

I just got a new slingshot. It's not very effective against monsters but it's fun to take potshots at Shane when I see him.

Hitting Shane makes the grumpy speech bubble appear above his head. Does that mean I lose friendship with people if I shoot them?

Comment: If your aiming is non lethal: likely!

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Yes, you'll lose some friendship, but not a lot.

Each heart level is 250 friendship points.

**Shooting someone takes away 30 friendship points, or 12% of a heart level.**

(Source: Snooping in the source code with a decompiler)

Answer (score 41):

Yes, hitting people with rocks will, not surprisingly, make them dislike you.

Comment: Does this also apply to tool like axes and pickaxes and hoes?

Comment: @Reafexus That should be its own question. Feel free to make a new question.

Comment: You claim this is not surprising. Do you have a source?

Comment: @acbabis Empirical observation.

Comment: I would claim this is only true if the person in question knows who actually threw the rock..

Comment: Does this only apply to thrown/launched rocks? Will bashing their head with a rock make you dislike them too?

Comment: @tox123: bashing their head with a stone amkes em assume this stone in their face is meant to be a present. So here the opposite is true ;)