# Does hitting people with basic tools cause them to dislike you?

Tags: stardew-valley

Similar to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/258362/does-shooting-people-make-them-dislike-me), does hitting people with tools cause them to not like you? Unlike the other question I have never seen an NPC react but I know I have accidentally swung an axe or hoe in the direction of them before.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't hit someone with a tool or a melee weapon.  When you swing one of these items, one of the things the game checks is whether your potential target is a monster.  Monsters can be whacked; ordinary NPCs (including animals) can't.

(Source: Snooping in the source code with a decompiler)

Comment: Such a godsend too, I always felt so bad in HM when I would smack my cows or chickens with an axe accidentally!